# "localhost" vs 127.0.0.1 java

Tags: java, network-programming, ip, inetaddress

Java is giving 127.0.0.1 as IP for **InetAddress.getByName("localhost").getHostAddress()**
But why java not gives "localhost" for InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1").getHostName. For later one I get "127.0.0.1" as host name. Please clarify this.

Comment: It returns whatever the underlying DNS system is returning, and there's no reverse mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javadoc of [`InetAddress.getByName(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29) states

> The host name can either be a machine name, such as "java.sun.com", or
>   a textual representation of its IP address. **If a literal IP address is
>   supplied, only the validity of the address format is checked.**

So it doesn't actually go to your `hosts` file (or DNS) for an IP address. It just creates a `InetAddress` object with both hostname and address created from the `String` you provided.

For your first example

```
InetAddress.getByName("localhost").getHostAddress()
```

Assuming you have a `hosts` file entry like

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
```

then the `InetAddress` object returned will have that information, ie. a hostname of `localhost` and an address of `127.0.0.1`.

Similarly, if you had

```
1.2.3.4    this.is.a.name
```

and

```
InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getByName("this.is.a.name");
```

The returned `InetAddress` would be constructed with a hostname of `this.is.a.name` and an address of `1.2.3.4`, because it actually went and checked.

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation, now I got how ip/hostname are mapped.