# Different behavior of InetSocketAddress#getHostName in windows and linux for "127.0.0.1"

Tags: java, networking

```java
InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1").getHostName()
```

The above `String` in windows returns `127.0.0.1` but in linux it returns `localhost`.

The docs of [`InetAddress#getHostName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostName--) says:

> If this InetAddress was created with a host name, this host name will be remembered and returned; otherwise, a reverse name lookup will be performed and the result will be returned based on the system configured name lookup service.

- Is this the expected behavior?
- Why is this discrepancy for different OS?
- Is it the case that the name-lookup service for linux and windows are different and that's the reason we are seeing this difference in the behavior?

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001426/localhost-vs-127-0-0-1-java), but my question is regarding the difference in behavior of the API in windows and linux and the reason of this difference.

Comment: The quotation is irrelevant. This `InetAddress` was constructed with an IP address, not a hostname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there is no main difference between Windows and Linux. There is a difference in the configuration of the two, though. As stated in the question that you referenced, it depends on what is inside of the `hosts` file. This is a file that is on both Windows and Linux, and it tells the OS what IP's can be assigned to specific hostnames. Here is an example entry in the file:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
```

This will tell the OS that if I make a request to `localhost`, just route the request to `127.0.0.1`. It is similar to what a DNS server does, but the process happens on your computer, without checking the internet.

Now, referring why that line changes on different platforms. The documentation says this:

> If this InetAddress was created with a host name, this host name will be remembered and returned; otherwise, **a reverse name lookup will be performed and the result will be returned based on the system configured name lookup service.** If a lookup of the name service is required, call getCanonicalHostName.

This section is referring to the hostname specified in the `hosts` file. On your Linux system, the `hosts` file has an entry that looks similar to the one above(which is quite common in Linux environments). Java notices this, and returns that instead of the IP. Since there is no such entry on Windows, it simple returns the IP, instead.